# How to update the value of a key in a json file without loading the complete json in python?

Tags: python, json, performance

Consider, the content of json file before the update is,

```
{"key1": "value A", "key2": "value B"}
```

I want to update the key1 to value C without actually opening the json file using json.load(). So the final output should be,

```
{"key1": "value C", "key2": "value B"}
```

I want something like update() in mongoDB. Is it possible through any library?

Comment: Im not quite sure how you would accomplish this. A JSON file is merely a text file, you will not be able to change its contents using Python without opening it. You mention mongoDB, that route would work. I know mongoDB works with unstructured JSON data, but the data is still stored in a file and is actually opened by mongoDB. If anyone else has better ideas I would love to see/hear about it.

Comment: With standard json library you cannot achieve that. What you are talking about is a kind of SAX parser (from xml), which does not load all the document tree into memory but instead parses the input stream and calling appropriate callbacks (handlers) upon finding nodes, attributes and etc.

So you setup text stream, reading from one file and writing to another. It should write the data unchanged until it finds the key. After that simply pipe the streams without further processing.

Comment: Thanks @mikeg. That's my thought process too. Since the MongoDB, which uses json, is doing it, I felt there should be a way to do this. I don't feel every time the file will be opened to update as it would bite their performance.

Comment: Thansk @grapes.! I can draw a map of how it is done. I understand it cannot be achieved through standard json libray. But do you know any other json parsing library which does that. I did a bit of exploration but all in vain.

Comment: If your json has predefined structure, as shown in the example, and it is not supposed to change, you can simply parse it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the context of the task. As I told in comment, you can use SAX parser instead of DOM. It will prevent you from building huge model in memory. SAX parsers work on event (callback)-driven mechanisms.

Another option, if your JSON structure is as simple as shown and is not expected to change, you can use simply regular expressions. The following example shows the idea, but be careful, it assumes, your values are always in form `[\w\d\s]*` and do not contains quotes and commas.

```
import re

rx = r'\s*\"(\w\d+)\"\s*:\s*"([\w\d\s]*)"\s*'

with open('in.json') as inp:
  src_text = inp.read().strip(' \t\r\n{}')
  output = []
  for pair in src_text.split(','):
      m = re.match(rx, pair)
      key = m.group(1)
      val = m.group(2)
      output.append('"{}": "{}"'.format(key, 'value C' if key == 'key1' else val))
  with open('out.json', 'w') as outp:
      outp.write('{' + ', '.join(output) + '}')
```