# Large JSON file: string search in dict values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a large JSON file with about 30,000 items which has items like:

```
d = {"1102344": "Install 3245 xxx", "23456": "Install 7896 zzz", "90887": "Install 6655 ddd"}
```

I've been trying to get the `key`, `value` for items that match `num` and `query` as in the example code below:

```
    def test(num, query):
        l = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if num in v and v.strip().startswith(query)]
        return l
    test('3245','Install')
#Output: [('1102344', 'Install 3245 xxx')]
```

The above code works as the dict `d` has few items. However, when I run this for my dataset, I get the following error:

```
argument of type `bool` is not iterable
```

I've searched around for help on SO and many answers point towards using `ijson` but I'm restricted to install third-party libraries. Is there a memory-efficient alternative way to search for substrings in the dict `values`? I've run out of options trying different things and not sure why I'm getting this error. The JSON is ordered and is valid.

Just to let you know, it used to work before but now I get this error 3 times out of 5. So the error appears intermittently but quite frequent for the app to do its job. There has been no change in the JSON file or the code whatsoever, however, the JSON file size has increased which makes me think that could be the reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495772/how-to-update-the-value-of-a-key-in-a-json-file-without-loading-the-complete-jso?noredirect=1#comment93931986_53495772

Comment: I bet `v` is getting a boolean value from somewhere. You should use a `try-except` block to see where and at what value you are getting the boolean value.

Comment: This problem has **nothing whatsoever** to do with JSON; it happens with native Python data structures as well. Part of building a [mcve] is generating the simplest possible reproducer; that includes eliminating things that aren't actually elements of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of json isn't problem here, problem is that probably some of values of your dict are `bools` (True of False) and so you can not treat them like strings by using `strip()` or `startswith()`. Here I added `'12345': False` entry yo our dict to induce this error.

```
d = {"1102344": "Install 3245 xxx", '12345': False, "23456": "Install 7896 zzz", "90887": "Install 6655 ddd"}

def test(num, query):
    l = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if type(v) is not bool and num in v and v.strip().startswith(query)]
    return l
print(test('3245','Install'))
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

---

What you could do is in your function first check whether value type isn't bool, or better if its string.

```
l = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if type(v) is str and num in v and v.strip().startswith(query)]
```

**Output:**

```
[('1102344', 'Install 3245 xxx')]
```

Comment: he should also probably add `and is not None` just in case as well

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much. I found the string "true" in my dataset which appears just once as a substring of a `value` string. In Python `True` is considered boolean so not sure if that caused it.

Comment: I suppose a memory-efficient way to iterate & search will be to use regex as suggested in the SO answer in comments. But that's not an immediate requirement as it takes about 10 secs to get what I want with this code for now.